# What type of ANOVA test should I use?

Tags: r, anova, ancova

I have 2 independent categorical variables with 2 groups each, say

1. **ind_1**
        -ind_1a
        -ind_1b
2. **ind2**
        -ind_2a
        -ind_2b

The outcome variable is quantitative and is measured at Pre_test, Post_test_30mins, Post_test_60mins.

The subjects were assigned to following groups, ind_1a, ind_1a + ind_2a, ind_1b, ind_1b+ ind_2a as shown below.
Here is a snapshot of my dataset, with dummy values.

[image]

For the above data which ANOVA test should I use? or is it an ANCOVA that is required??
I'm an R user, so help with the code is much appreciated!

Comment: So every participant have been measured three times? Pre_test, Post_test_30mins, Post_test_60mins. And too me it looks like, say subject A1 is present in all four groups ind_1a, ind_1a + ind_2a, ind_1b, ind_1b+ ind_2a?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.